# Loop is adding too many items to the final array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `config` that looks like this:

```
{
  payTable: [
    {name: 'rouge',     reelCount: [10,10,10,10,10]},
    {name: 'wolfman',   reelCount: [10,10,10,10,10]},
    {name: 'sorceress', reelCount: [10,10,10,10,10]},
    {name: 'ace',       reelCount: [10,10,10,10,10]},
    {name: 'king',      reelCount: [10,10,10,10,10]},
    {name: 'queen',     reelCount: [10,10,10,10,10]},
    {name: 'jack',      reelCount: [10,10,10,10,10]},
    {name: 'wild',      reelCount: [10,10,10,10,10]}
  ],
  rules: {
    cols: 5
  }
}
```

The item `config.payTable.reelCount` is an array of how many items of this type should be in the final array. The length of this array will always be the same size as `config.rules.cols`.

Here is what I am doing. First I create an array of arrays called `reels` which will be an array with `config.rules.cols` as the total number of child arrays.

Next I loop through the `config.payTable`, then through `config.payTable.reelCount` to get how many times that item should be in `reels[x]` I then add it that many times.

The issue that I am running into is that it creating 5 arrays with 400 items in each array. What I need is for it to create 5 arrays with 80 items in each array (`10x8=80` where 10 is the number from reelCount, and 8 is the number of items).

```
let reels = new Array(config.rules.cols).fill([])
// Creates an array that looks like this:
// [ [],[],[],[],[] ]

config.payTable.forEach((item, itemIdx) => {
  item.reelCount && item.reelCount.forEach((times, countIdx) => {
    for (let k = 0; k < times; k++) {
      reels[countIdx].push(item)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: `.fill([])` results in the same array for each element. Use `.fill( 0 ).map( () => [] )` for a unique array for each element.

Comment: WOW... That completely fixes the problem.

Comment: @vox Feel free to post an answer in the duplicate link as the only answers there only describes the problem, not solving it.